# Who triggers transistors to become H/L?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, relay, flipflop, logic-gates

Admittedly that's quite a beginner question:

When I learned that transistors work like relays and produce the digital values 0 and 1 what I always asked myself was: they have to be triggered by someone, but by whom?

When I turn the light on and off, then it's me who triggers the relay but who is it in an electric circuit or within a CPU? Or when thinking about a flipflop, who tells the transistors to go to 0 or 1?

I never understood how that happens, I image it like the chicken or the egg causality dilemma.

Comment: They are triggered by an external signal. Sometimes its you, the user, and other times its another part of a circuit.

Answer (score 2):

In very most cases (maybe 99.999%) the transistors of digital circuits are triggered by the output signal of other transistors.

The remaining few cases are interfaces to the non-electrical or analog world:
peripherals like keys (interfaces to digital but not electrical signals), ADCs (interfaces to electrical signals thar are not digital), oscillators, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Individual transistors are amplifiers. They may handle very small voltage changes in analog circuits, or in digital circuits they are driven to turn fully on or off, in order to give the voltages that correspond to 0 and 1 (typically 0 is 0V and 1 is +5V).

A flip-flop or "bistable" circuit needs two transistors. They are wired to stay in whichever of the states ON-OFF or OFF-ON they were last put into. Like the spring in an ordinary light switch keeps the switch as you last set it.

In order to change the state, a pulse of energy must be applied. Like your hand that pushes the light switch.

Do inspect the description of the flip-flop which is fundamental to all computing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistable_circuit
It is really more predictable than chickens.

Answer (score 0):

Transistors inside the CPU are switched depending on user defined program code.

To run a CPU, you need program code which can be executed. When powering, most CPUs start with program code address 0. The byte at that address tells the CPU what to do. After executing the command, the CPU goes to the next address and so on.

For example the program code for "load 3" (on a [Zilog Z80](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/computers/tandy/software/apps/m4/qd/opcodes.html).):

`3E 03`, whereas this is in hexadecimal format.

`3E` means load. With these bits, the CPU can **trigger transistors** to do what the command tells him to. In this case load the following Byte. The following Byte then is `03` which is exactly what we want to load. This is done by logic gates in [digital circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_electronics).

For every command, there is a "code" and every code triggers the internal transistors differenty. These codes vary for every CPU. Windows PCs usually have x86 architecture CPUs, that differ greatly from the Z80 CPU used for the example.